# If input not existing ( in dataset ) than display generic content

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm working on a website with some kind of a JavaScript "input" tabs. Let say user type "running" in input and press submit than application display some quote about running, but when user type something that is not exist in predefined dataset (data-name) than application display  generic content.

Everything is working except generic content(class="generic").

How can I add generic content when input value is not existing in dataset values in the app section.

You can try in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/e10nLbg2/1/

Here is my code:

```
.data, .generic {
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
    background: blue;
    padding: 50px;
    color: white;
    transition: opacity 1s ease;
    position: absolute;
}

.active {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
}


<input type="text" class="input">
<input type="submit" class="submit" value="SUBMIT">

<section class="app">

<div class="data" data-name="running">RUNNING - Lorem ipsum dolor sit...
</div>

<div class="data" data-name="walking">WALKING - Lorem ipsum dolor 
sit...
</div>

<div class="generic">GENERIC - Lorem ipsum dolor sit...
</div>
</section>


var submit = document.querySelector('.submit');

submit.onclick = function(){
var input = document.querySelector('.input').value;
var e = input.toLowerCase();
var element = document.querySelector('[data-name="'+ e +'"]');

var generic = document.querySelector('.generic');
var active = document.querySelector('.active');


if(active){
  active.classList.remove('active');
  //generic.classList.add('active');
}else{
  //generic.classList.remove('active');
}

 element.classList.add('active');

}
```

Answer (score 0):

On submit event you need to remove `.active` from active element and generic one as well, then set active the one that fits user input, else - set active generic:

```js
var submit = document.querySelector('.submit');
 
 submit.onclick = function() {
     let e = document.querySelector('.input').value.toLowerCase();
     let element = document.querySelector('[data-name="'+ e +'"]');
     let generic = document.querySelector('.generic');
     let active = document.querySelector('.active');
    
     if (active) active.classList.remove('active');
     generic.classList.remove('active');
     
     if (element) 
        element.classList.add('active');
     else
        generic.classList.add('active');
}
```

```css
.data, .generic {
visibility: hidden;
opacity: 0;
background: blue;
padding: 50px;
color: white;
transition: opacity 1s ease;
position: absolute;
}

.active {
visibility: visible;
opacity: 1;
}

input {
height: 30px;
border-radius: 5px;
box-sizing: border-box;
outline: none;
}

input[type="text"] {
background: #e6e6e6;
color: grey;
outline: none;
padding: 15px;
border: 0;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="input">
 <input type="submit" class="submit" value="SUBMIT">


 <div class="data" data-name="running">RUNNING - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</div>
 
 <div class="data" data-name="playing">PLAYING - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</div>
 
 <div class="data" data-name="dancing">DANCING - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</div>
 
 <div class="data" data-name="walking">WALKING - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</div>

 <div class="generic">GENERIC - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</div>
```